# clCreateFromGLTexture() returns CL_INVALID_CONTEXT on certain platforms only

Tags: qt, opengl, interop, opencl

After positive creation of the shared context between OpenGL and OpenCL using following:

```
cl_context_properties cps[] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,
    (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR,
    (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
    (cl_context_properties)platform_id,
    0
};

// Create an OpenCL context
m_contextCL = clCreateContext( cps, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
```

I try to create a shared texture:

```
cl_mem mem = clCreateFromGLTexture(
            m_contextCL ,
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY ,
            GL_TEXTURE_2D ,
            0 ,
            qt_fbo->texture() ,
            &err
            );
```

Now the call is successful only on xubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA Quadro K620 using proprietary driver version 387.26 and OpenCL delivered with CUDA implementation package.

However when trying it on Toshiba laptop with Intel HD Graphics 520 on Manjaro OS and Beignet OpenCL implementation. The clCreateFromGLTexture(...) is failing by returning CL_INVALID_CONTEXT,
Additionally I tried another platform with Ubuntu 16.04 and Intel Iris IGP (Integrated Graphics Processor) using both Intel SDK and Beignet OpenCL. It fails at the same point of shared texture creation.

I created minimum working example for comparison two GPU techniques (OpenGL and OpenCL) and its interoperability with Qt: 

 https://github.com/pietrzakmat/opengl-opencl-qt-interop.

 All the steps are derived from two tutorials:

 1. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685281/OpenGL-OpenCL-Interoperability-A-Case-Study-Using

 2. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial

Anyone could point out what am I doing wrong and why the creation of shared texture fails on the platforms with integrated graphics or IGP Intel cpu? Is this some problem with drivers or OpenCL implementations? I managed to build and run the samples included in Beignet or intel_ocl_examples so I think the installation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1) is supported cl_khr_gl_sharing extension? Did you try to use this code on Windows Platform/macOS for Intel GPU  ?
2) Did you try to use texture without attached to FBO ?

any way, i think this is problem in OpenCL implementation on Linux platform.